Binomial determinant and LU decomposition
Let $A_n$ be following $n \times n$ symmetric pentadiagonal matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
6&4&1&& \\
4&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\\
1&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&1\\
&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&4\\
&&1&4&6\\
\end{pmatrix}_{n\times n}
$$
with entries of binomial expansion $(x+1)^4$.
I want to prove formula for its determinant
$$
|A_n|=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)^2(n+3)}{12}.
$$
There are several possibilities how to do it, for instance by solving recurrence relation from https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0898122116300232
or by using method in https://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/hyperfactorialBRIEF.pdf,
but I want to prove it using LU decomposition just like as special case in paper https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1972-26-118/S0025-5718-1972-0303703-3/S0025-5718-1972-0303703-3.pdf#page16, but I don’t understand argumentation in proof of Theorem 1 - I don’t know why matrix $L_n$ is always lower triangular.
They are working with symmetric pentadiagonal matrix with entries of binomial expansion $(x-1)^4$, but their method could be easily transformed into my case by “cleverly putting” minus sign to matrix $U_n$.
It seems to work, for example $n=6$:
$$
A_6=
\begin{pmatrix}
6&4&1&0&0&0\\
4&6&4&1&0&0\\
1&4&6&4&1&0\\
0&1&4&6&4&1\\
0&0&1&4&6&4\\
0&0&0&1&4&6\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
U_6=
\begin{pmatrix}
-1&-2&-3&-4&-5&-6\\
0&3&6&9&12&15\\
0&0&-6&-12&-18&-24\\
0&0&0&10&20&30\\
0&0&0&0&-15&-30\\
0&0&0&0&0&21\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and finally:
$$
A_6 U_6=
\begin{pmatrix}
-6&0&0&0&0&0\\ 
-4&10&0&0&0&0\\
-1&10&-15&0&0&0\\
0&3&-18&21&0&0\\
0&0&-6&28&-28&0\\
0&0&0&10&-40&36\\
\end{pmatrix},
$$
which is clearly lower triangular matrix and lets call it $L_6$.
The rest is easy using multiplicativity of determinant and fact determinant of lower/upper triangular matrix equals product of terms on the main diagonal:
$$
|U_6|=(-1)(3)(-6)(10)(-15)(21)
$$
$$
|L_6|=(-6)(10)(-15)(21)(-28)(36)
$$
$$
|L_6|=|A_6 U_6|=|A_6||U_6|,
$$
so
$$
|A_6|=\frac{|L_6|}{|U_6|}=\frac{(-28)(36)}{(-1)(3)}=(28)(12)=336
$$
which equals closed form for $n=6$:
$$
\frac{(6+1)(6+2)^2(6+3)}{12}=336.
$$
My question is how to prove that for general $n$ using this method based on LU decomposition, or more specifically how to prove matrix $A_nU_n:=L_n$ is lower triangular for any $n$ (because the rest should be easy).

The paper which you have linked has
$$\begin{align}
a_{ij} = (-1)^{r+i-j}\binom{2r}{r+i-j} & & U_{ij} &= \binom{i+r-1}{r}\binom{j+r-1-i}{r-1} \cdot [j \geq i]
\end{align}$$
From this, it follows that for $L = AU$, we get
$$
L_{ij} = \sum\limits_k a_{ik} U_{kj} = \sum\limits_k (-1)^{r+i-k}\binom{2r}{r+i-k} \binom{k+r-1}{r} \binom{j+r-1-k}{r-1} \cdot [j \geq k]
$$
In your case, however,
$$\begin{align}
a_{ij}' = \binom{2r}{r+i-j} & & U_{ij}' &= (-1)^{i}\binom{i+r-1}{r}\binom{j+r-1-i}{r-1} \cdot [j \geq i]
\end{align}$$
With this, the value of $L_{ij}'$ for $L' = A'U'$ can be found as
$$
L_{ij}' = \sum\limits_k a_{ik}' U_{kj}' = \sum\limits_k (-1)^k \binom{2r}{r+i-k} \binom{k+r-1}{r} \binom{j+r-1-k}{r-1} \cdot [j \geq k] = (-1)^{r+i} L_{ij}
$$
Note that you have $r=2$, so basically the $i$-th row of $L'$ is simply the $i$-th row of $L$ multiplied by $(-1)^i$.

Now, assuming that we do not know that $L$ from the article is lower-triangular, how to prove it?
The rationale from the article is that multiplication of $A$ by a column-vector $x(i)$ applies the transform
$$x(i) \to x(i+1)-2x(i)+x(i-1),$$
to it $r$ times in a row. This transform is called the second "central difference", and you can prove by induction that the coefficients after applying it $r$ times are the coefficients of $(x^2-2x+1)^r = (x-1)^{2r}$, which are, in turn, the coefficients of $A$.
You can also represent second central difference as the combination of transforms $x(i) \to x(i+1)-x(i)$ and $x(i) \to x(i) - x(i-1)$. From this, it follows that if $x(i)$ is a polynomial, applying second central difference to it $r$ times will reduce the degree of the polynomial by $2r$. Also note that the final value of $x(i)$ only depends on the initial values of $x(i-r),\dots,x(i+r)$, and not the elements beyond.
So, the article defines $U_{ij}$ in such way that for any $j$, when $i < j + r$, it holds that $U_{ij} = u_j(i)$, where
$$
u_j(i) = \binom{i+r-1}{r} \binom{j+r-1-i}{r-1}.
$$
It means that first $j+r-1$ rows of the $j$-th column are the values of the same polynomial $u_j(i)$ in $i$ of degree $2r-1$, so after applying the second central difference to its values $r$ times, they will turn into $0$ for all $i$ such that $i+r<j+r$.
On the other hand, multiplying $A$ by $U$ is same as individually applying $A$ to each column of $U$. Therefore, in the $j$-th column of the result, first $j-1$ rows will be zero, proving that it would be a lower-triangular matrix. $\square$

Small detail: Let $x(i)_n$, $i \in {1, \dots, n}$ be any $n$-vector. Applying transformation $x(i) \rightarrow x(i+1)-2x(i)+x(i-1)$ to the  $n$-vector, where $x(0)=x(n+1)=0$,  is the same as multiplying tridiagonal $n$-matrix  $1,-2,1$ by $n$-vector. And doing that transformation $r$-times is the same as multiplying $r$-th power of same tridiagonal matrix by same $n$-vector. However $r$-th power of that tridiagonal matrix is NOT equal to any of diagonal matrices with binomial coefficients (easy to check), so in the paragraph with link to central difference is small mistake.
